# Converting pandas column to string w/o scientific notation

Tags: python, pandas

Lots of questions address this, but none of the solutions seem to work exactly as I need.

I have a dataframe with two columns of numbers with 10-20 digits each.  These are actually ID #s, and I'd like to concatenate them.  It looks like that's best done by first converting the values to strings.

However, when converting with `.astype(str)`, pandas keeps the scientific notation, which won't fly.

Things I've tried:

tried: dtype arg ('str') or converters (using `str()`) in `read_csv()`

outcome: `df.dtypes` still lists 'objects,' and values still display in sci. notation

tried: `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x)`

outcome:  displays good in `df.head()`, but reverts to scientific notation upon coercion to string & concatenation using + operator

tried:  coercing to int, str, or `str(int(x))`.
outcome:  int works when i coerce one value with `int()`, but not when I use `astype(int)`.  using `.apply()` with `int()` throws an 'invalid literal long() with base 10' error.

This feels like it should be pretty straightforward, anxious to figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tried sets the display format. You could just format the float as a string in the dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
```

import pandas as pd

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'a':np.random.randint(low=1,high=100,size=10)*1e20,'b':np.random.randint(low=1,high=100,size=10)*1e20})
df.apply(lambda x: '{0:20.0f}|{1:20.0f}'.format(x.a,x.b),axis=1)



Out[34]:
0    9699999999999998951424|4600000000000000000000
1     300000000000000000000|2800000000000000000000
2    9400000000000000000000|9000000000000000000000
3    2100000000000000000000|4500000000000000000000
4    5900000000000000000000|4800000000000000000000
5    7700000000000000000000|6200000000000000000000
6    1600000000000000000000|8000000000000000000000
7      100000000000000000000|400000000000000000000
8    9699999999999998951424|8000000000000000000000
9    4500000000000000000000|3500000000000000000000
```

Comment: thank you, this is a nice & simple solution.  Still working on this, though, since trying to implement this solution actually revealed an error in my data where pandas is parsing some values as float.  Once I sort that out, I think this'll do the trick.

Comment: Yep, forgot to click 'correct answer.'  Thanks again!

for posterity:  i just had to write an apply() function that cast each row as float64, then concatenated using your technique.  Some were un-castable, so the function discarded those rows.